# how to get values in a column corresponding to other values in two columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have 4 columns which are ( "from node", "via node", "to node" , "angle"), I grouped "via node" by maximum "angle", so I got 2 new columns, what I want to do next is to get the corresponding value from "from node" and put it in a column at the new data frame beside "vianode" and "angle"

for example: I should go to the original data frame and check "viaNode" let us say it is (1) , so the maximum angle corresponding  to it is (238), so i have to search using these two values (vianode=1, angle=238) and get the corresponding "fromnode" value, which will be (8) at this example.

Comment: Can you provide some code to illustrate?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide some code or example of your tables so that we can help you. You can refer to this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples/32536193#32536193) on how to provide a reproducible pandas problem.